# Android Navigation Component: Fragment with attached listener object

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation, arguments, android-architecture-navigation

I have `Fragment B`

```
class FragmentB : Fragment() {
    private var myListener: MyListener? = null
    
    ... //onCreate and other methods
    ...

    fun setListener(listener: MyListener) {
        myListener = listener
    }
}
```

which starts from a random `Activity A` with a custom listener attached to it:

```
        val fragment = FragmentB.newInstance()

        val myListener = object : MyListener {
            override fun someMethodA() {
                //action 1
            }
            override fun someMethodB() {
                //action 2
            }
        }

        fragment.setListener(myListener)
        //show fragment here...
```

**What i want** 
I have to create a bottom sheet that open and show `Fragment A` and then when a button is pressed it shows the previous `Fragment B`. All the implementation in the bottom sheet is built with `Navigation Component` and with the implementation of the `navGraph`. 
I have succesfully implemented it and shows both `Fragment A` and `Fragment B` inside the bottom sheet but i cannot find a way to add the listener to `Fragment B`.

**I tried**

- To add an `OnDestionationChangedListener` to my `navController` and then find the current visible fragment and `attach the listener`

```
 NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->
     when (destination.id) {
          R.id.fragmentB -> {
              attachListenerToFragmentB(myListener)
          }
     }
 }
```

```
private fun attachListenerToFragmentB(myListener: MyListener) {
   val fragment = fragmentManager?.fragments?.filterNotNull()?.find {
       it.javaClass.name == (navController?.currentDestination as FragmentNavigator.Destination).className 
       ?: return
   }

   if (fragment is FragmentB)
       fragment.setListener(myListener)
}
```

This adds the listener to the fragment but after that the `Navigation Component` reCreates the `FragmentB` so the `listener` is again null.

Note that the navigation from `Fragment A` to `Fragment B` inside the bottom sheet fragment happens after

```
val action = EntryPointFragmentDirections.navigateToFragmentB()
action.id = id  // just some arguments
findNavController().navigate(action)
```

Any help to find a way to use that `Fragment B` with it's `listener` both the old way and also with the `Navigation Component`?

Comment: This approach is never, ever going to work consistently, since a config change or process death and recreation is going to wipe out any listener you've set (which is why this pattern has not ever, ever been recommended). Is there a reason you aren't following the [guidance for returning a result](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-programmatic#returning_a_result) or [Communicating between fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate)?

Comment: The reason is that FragmentB is already exists and is a big fragment and that listener has a lot of things. It is not simple as my example and i have no intent to change it @ianhanniballake

Comment: Then your code is already not working since the approach you've detailed has never worked and will immediately break after a configuration change (e.g., rotating your device) or process death and recreation (e.g. using the "Don't keep activities" developer option).